# Weird group name ( 1002)

Tags: permissions, file-system

Please forgive me if this is the wrong place to ask this, but I ran ls -l on an ubuntu machine today in /etc and found a few entries like the following middle entry which appears to have spaces in front of the GID.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      92 Apr  9 11:10 host.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   1002    25 Aug 13 05:26 hostname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     116 Aug 13 05:26 hosts
```

Tried to run a few different commands to get the group name from the GID like:

```
getent group %20%201002 | cut -d: -f1
```

and

```
getent group \ \ 1002 | cut -d: -f1
```

But nothing.

Read up a little on Linux GIDs and POSIX says this [shouldn't be possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401752/how-to-add-to-group-when-name-has-a-space).

Is this something to be concerned about security-wise?

And can someone perhaps offer an explanation?

Google doesn't seem to know anything about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `hostname` file is owned by group ID 1002, and there is no entry in `/etc/group` mapping any group name to GID 1002, so `ls -l` simply shows the group number instead of a name.  And when a bare GID is displayed, unlike a named group, it is right-justified, making it look like it has leading spaces compared to any longer group names.  Here you can see with three files that I created and gave user/group ownerships that would demonstrate this:

```
$ ls -l foo*
-rw-r--r-- 1 gowenfawr          1002 0 Aug 23 01:29 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-resolve nogroup 0 Aug 23 01:30 foo2
-rw-r--r-- 1 gowenfawr       cdrom   0 Aug 23 01:33 foo3
$
```

There's no particular security concern here, except perhaps that somehow your `/etc/hostname` file got it's group ownership changed.  You might want to search for any users which belong to that group:

```
$ awk -F: '$4 == 1002 {print $0}' /etc/passwd
```

and you might want to search for other files with that group ownership:

```
$ find /etc -gid 1002 -ls
   136023      4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root   1002    25 Aug 13 05:26 /etc/hostname
```

If you were to find that, say, `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` were owned by 1002, that would like indicate a serious security concern.

If, as you comment, `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces` are also owned by that file, then you almost certainly have a DHCP client or other network manager that is managing those files and setting the group ownership to 1002 when it updates them, likely in response to a configuration file that says to use GID 1002.  A blunt way to check for this would be

```
$ grep -r 1002 /etc/*
```

but that may have a false positive or two.  If you find a networky named config file with an entry like "group = 1002" then that's your culprit :)

Comment: Loving your edits and updates on this; extremely educational answer so far.

Comment: No other users belonging to group, but /resolv.conf and /network/interfaces both have the same permissions. Does that look normal as well? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @uofc glad to help :).  If this works for you, you can upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer.  And if you find that config file please comment so I can add that to the answer!

Comment: Right on! Huge help so far. Output from grep found this: /etc/rpc:sgi_fam  391002. Look familiar? Thank you again in advance. Marking this awesome solution as answered right now.

Comment: @uofc `/etc/rpc` is the Remote Procedure Call mapping file - like /etc/group, but for RPC programs instead of for user groups.  So, no, that's not something that would affect file ownership of the network files.